# Use string as date input with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We often have the situation where we have database fields such as dates, datetimes, currencies, … for which the user enters data as a string. This means that the data needs to be casted before it can be stored in the database.

Currently, we're using a concept like the following (we have a library for that, but it essentially boils down to this). In this example, we have a physical date attribute called `valid_from`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :valid_from_str, :string

  def valid_from_str=(value)
     begin
       self.valid_from = Date.parse(value)
     rescue
       self.valid_from = nil
     end

     super
  end

  def valid_from_str
    some_date_format_method(valid_from)
  end

  validate do |user|
    begin
      Date.parse(user.valid_from_str)
    rescue
      user.errors.add :valid_from_str, :invalid
    end
  end
end
```

So as you can see, we create an additional, virtual attribute called `valid_from_str` that provides us with a getter and setter we can use in forms and it also validates the correct date format.

This is a lot of tinkering though and I think this must somehow be possible using Rails 5 custom attribute types, something like:

```
class CustomDate < ActiveRecord::Type::Date
  def cast(value)
    if value.is_a?(String)
      return Date.parse(value)
    else
      return value
    end
  end
end
```

This basically works, but it does not allow us to validate the original string value provided by the user.

Is there a way of achieving the example above using the attributes API?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base` does the same things with `Date` and `DateTime` attributes as you do in your getter and setter methods.  I mean you should remove those methods and rewrite your question.

Comment: @chumakoff With the built-in functionality I'm unable to specify a specific date format and unable to validate the format properly.

Comment: Using `Date.strptime("08/21/2018", "%m/%d/%Y")` allows to specify the format. You can use it in your `validate do ... end` block as well as in `CustomDate`

Comment: Yes, I know that. The above is just simplified to show the actual problem. The problem is that the original (faulty) string can not be validated in the example I've provided.

Comment: The `valid_from_str` getter method should return the original string. In that case everything will work.

Comment: Thanks, that's how we've actually implemented it now. But is it possible to achieve that using custom AR types? I think my approach feels kind of hacky. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178462/discussion-between-chumakoff-and-remo).